# Integrate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^{(x-\alpha)\beta}+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I need to solve for the parameter $\alpha$ after I calculate the integral.$$
\mathcal{R}(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^{(x-\alpha)\beta}+1}dx, \ \ \beta >0
$$ The result of this integral is
$$
\mathcal{R}(\alpha,\beta)=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\beta^{\frac32}}\text{Li}_{\frac32}{(-e^{\beta\alpha})}
$$ Thanks to David H solution below.  However, I need to invert this result now and solve for $\alpha$.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}dx=\Gamma(n+1)\zeta(n+1)\qquad;\qquad \int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}dx=\Gamma(n+1)\eta(n+1)$$

Comment: Thanks, but those are not useful here. This answer is expressed in terms of polylogs.  Note the exponent is not just $e^x$, it is shifted by $x-\alpha$, so the result is slightly different here.  The simple case is when $\alpha=0$ and you get what you posted above(Bose Integral)

Comment: Actually, they *are*. The $\zeta$ function itself is a polylogarithm, of offset $1$. In this case, that offset needs to be changed to an expression in *a* and *b*. And, of course, for $n=\dfrac12$ we have $\Gamma\bigg(1+\dfrac12\bigg)=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2$ .

Comment: You wrote
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{e^x+1}dx=\Gamma(n+1)\eta(n+1).
$$
What is $\eta(n+1)$?  And if they are related, how do you invert them?

Comment: See [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to invert PolyLogs?

Comment: *No one* knows how to invert polylogarithms. :-) Or $\zeta(x)$. Or $\Gamma(x)$. Etc. What I mean is that there are no closed form expressions for the inverses of these special functions. The only approach is by way of numerical methods.

Comment: Oh.  I didn't know that @Lucian.  You just taught me three different things from this problem.  So thanks.

Comment: Do I understand the problem correctly telling that knowing the value of $\mathcal{R}(\alpha,\beta)$, you want to know the value of $\alpha$ ?

Comment: $\mathcal{R}$ is a constant, solve for $\alpha$

Comment: Use Mathematica's inbuild *FindRoot[]* function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leting $u=\beta x$ and $a=\alpha\beta$,

$$\mathcal{R}(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^{(x-\alpha)\beta}+1}dx\\
=\beta^{-3/2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{u}}{e^{(u-a)}+1}du\\
=\beta^{-3/2}\mathcal{R}(a,1)=\beta^{-3/2}\mathcal{R}(\alpha\beta,1).$$

So it suffices to evaluate the integral for the $\beta=1$ case, and the case for general $\beta>0$ will follow automatically.

For this definite integral, Wolfram Alpha gives a result

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{u}}{e^{(u-a)}+1}du=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{Li}_{\frac32}{(-e^a)}$$

Thus,

$$\mathcal{R}(\alpha,\beta)=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\beta^{\frac32}}\text{Li}_{\frac32}{(-e^{\beta\alpha})}.$$

I'm not sure how to invert this formula however.

Comment: Yes I was able to get this as well, but inverting is what I am specifically looking for.  Thanks. Do you have any ideas how to invert?  You are close ;]

Comment: @Jeff Ah, darn. Do you have a reason to suspect it can actually be done, or are you just shooting in the dark?

Comment: Well I will check your as the solution if nobody else can figure it out, but I do suspect it can be done.  I expect it can be done as $\alpha$ is a physical parameter that I can solve for.  How about inverting up to 2nd or 3rd order?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that you could analytically invert the formula and then, the only way I can think about is numerical solution. If th value of $\mathcal{R}(\alpha,\beta)$ is given, as well as the value of $\alpha$ or $\beta$, Newton method would be quite efficient.

If you want me to more elaborate on this topic, please give me numbers for $\mathcal{R}(\alpha,\beta)$,  $\alpha$ or $\beta$ and I should illustrate the example.

**Added later to my answer**

Let us suppose that $\beta$ be given. So we have to solve, for $x=\alpha \beta$, the equation $$k=-\frac{2 \beta ^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\mathcal{R}(\alpha,\beta)=\text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(-e^x\right)$$ Using Newton method, starting at $x=0$, the first iterate is $$x=\frac{k+\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ Using Halley, we should arrive for the first iterate to $$x=\frac{\left(7+5 \sqrt{2}\right) \left(\left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) \zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-2 k\right) \left(\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)
   \left(\left(4 \sqrt{2}-2\right) k+\left(5 \sqrt{2}-6\right) \zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)+4 \left(2 \sqrt{2}-3\right) \zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)}{8 \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3}$$ If you really want the true solution, forget these estimates and use Newton iterations up to convergence. If $$f(x)=\text{Li}_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(-e^x\right)-k$$ $$f'(x)=\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-e^x\right)$$

Comment: THAnks, but what If we just wanted to invert it up to 2nd order?  Explicitly what I mean is to write an expression for $\alpha(\beta)$ up to 2nd order?  I do not have numbers for them.

Comment: Is $\beta$ assigned a fixed value ?

Comment: $\beta\propto 1/T$ where T is the temperature, and the temperature is positive and can change.

Comment: For a given value of $\beta$, we can do something (with no guarantee). I add something to my answer.

Comment: Okay I look forward to seeing...

Comment: Can you explain what you did to get these results?  I am not familiar with your methods.  Thanks. what is the first iterate?? and what is Halley?  Thanks I appreciate your help

Comment: Starting with guess (which has been taken as $0$ in my naswer), I use Newton second order method or Halley third order method to generate a first estimate. These methods are used for solving ieratively nonlinear equations (just google for them). The guess is updated by the iterate until convergence is met.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large a}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{\cal R}\pars{\alpha,\beta} \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}{%
     \root{x} \over \expo{\pars{x - \alpha}\beta} + 1}\,\dd x\,,\quad \beta > 0}$

> I found that the OP result is true  whenever $\ds{\large\alpha < 0\mbox{!!!}}$:

\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large{\cal R}\pars{\alpha,\beta}}&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\root{x}\,{%
\expo{-\pars{x - \alpha}\beta} \over 1 + \expo{-\pars{x - \alpha}\beta}}\,\dd x
=\beta^{-1}\int_{x = 0}^{x \to \infty}\root{x}\,
\dd\ln\pars{{1 + \expo{-\pars{x - \alpha}\beta}}}
\\[3mm]&=\beta^{-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{{1 + \expo{-\pars{x - \alpha}\beta}}}\,
\half\,x^{-1/2}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\half\,\beta^{-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{-1}^{\ell + 1} \over \ell}\,\expo{-\ell\pars{x - \alpha}\beta}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\half\,\beta^{-1}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{\ell + 1} \over \ell}\,
\expo{\ell\alpha\beta}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}
\expo{-\ell\beta x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\half\,\beta^{-1}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{\ell + 1} \over \ell}\,
\expo{\ell\alpha\beta}\,{1 \over \pars{\ell\beta}^{1/2}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}\expo{-x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\Gamma\pars{\half} = \root{\pi}}}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\root{\pi} \over 2\beta^{3/2}}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{-\expo{\alpha\beta}}^{\ell} \over \ell^{3/2}}
=\color{#00f}{\large -\,{\root{\pi} \over 2\beta^{3/2}}\,
{\rm Li}_{3/2}\pars{-\expo{\alpha\beta}}}
\end{align}

> Since this integral is linked to a Fermi-Dirac statistics, $\ds{\alpha < 0}$ corresponds to a non degenerated Fermi gas which should be true for 'small' values of $\beta$.

Comment: Very nice as always, I see you have a physics background.  (I do not, I am self taught)  So thanks for this knowledge as well.

Comment: how do we invert the result, or get physical quantities out of it?  If we can invert it, we do not need to use the Sommerfeld expansion to calculate integrals of the form
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(\epsilon)\frac{d\epsilon}{e^{(\epsilon-\mu)\beta}}=\int_{-\infty}^\mu H(\epsilon) d\epsilon + \zeta(2)\beta^{-2}H'(\mu)+O(\beta \mu)^{-4},\quad \beta\equiv\frac{1}{k_B T}.
$$